# Custom PreferenceCategory Headings

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I have a simple preference screen defined like this

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Security">
        <CheckBoxPreference 
            android:title="Require Pin on Start"
            android:summary="Require pin to run the application"
            android:key="@string/pref_require_pin"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Settings">
        <ListPreference
           android:title="History Age (in days)"
           android:summary="Display items up to 30 days old"
           android:key="@string/pref_history_days"
           android:defaultValue="30"
           android:entries="@array/days_list"
           android:entryValues="@array/days_list"
           android:dialogTitle="Select History Age"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I have a style setup already and used elsewhere in my app.

```
<style name="ListHeader">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#cccccc</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">6px</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">6px</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">12px</item>
</style>
```

and here is my activity

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);
    }
}
```

How do I apply my custom style to the `PreferenceCategory` heading?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You should take a look at [`Preference.Category`](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/styles.xml;h=d7b654e49809cb97a35682754b1394af5c8bc88b;hb=HEAD#l595) style:

```
<style name="Preference.Category">
    <item name="android:layout">@android:layout/preference_category</item>
   <item name="android:shouldDisableView">false</item>
   <item name="android:selectable">false</item>
</style>
```

Let's take a look at `preference_category.xml` file:

```
<!-- Layout used for PreferenceCategory in a PreferenceActivity. -->
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:id="@+android:id/title"
/>
```

So you need to create custom theme that extends default android `Theme` and override `listSeparatorTextViewStyle` value with `ListHeader` style. And then apply this theme to Activity that extends `PreferenceActivity` .

---

Here is how you can do it.

**First**, in your `styles.xml` add next code:

```
<style name="PreferenceListHeader" 
       parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.ListSeparator">

    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#cccccc</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">6px</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">6px</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">12px</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Custom" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/PreferenceListHeader</item>               
</style>
```

**Then** in your `AndroidManifest.xml` add theme to your preference acitivity:

```
 <activity android:name=".MyPreferencesActivity" 
           android:theme="@style/Theme.Custom" 
           ... >
 ...
 </activity>
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how to override `listSeparatorTextViewStyle`

Comment: Awesome.  That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: you don't have to use a style you can just use the android:layout attribute on the PreferenceCategory

Comment: @schwiz - Your comment is great, but the layout that I added doesn't display the "title" attribute. Is there an example layout.xml file that works with your suggestion?

Comment: Got some problems with "@android:style/Widget.TextView.ListSeparator", so I replaced it with "@android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle". Don't forget to define layout_height and layout_width.

Comment: @CamilleSévigny here is a link to the layout in the android repo https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/gingerbread/core/res/res/layout/preference.xml

Comment: "error retrieving parent for item: No resources found that matches the given name @android:style/Widget.TextView.ListSeparator"

Comment: maybe use @android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle instead as said above

Comment: @CamilleSévigny you need to use id as `android:id="@android:id/title"` then it will pick automatically! P.S: Know its late may help some one some day :)

Comment: please note Lollipop uses different styles for preferences and categories. Take a look at https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-mr1-release/core/res/res/values/styles_material.xml#L57

Comment: This answer just doesn't work anymore. android:style/Widget.TextView.ListSeparator doesn't exist, and android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle" doesn't exist either.  If you try to do exactly what's in this solution but pick any existing style to get it to compile, the app just crashes.  I can't believe this is so messed up.

Answer (score 19):

@inazaruk gave the answer well enough but since the recent updates, `ADT 18 and above`, there are some restrictions on the `styles` giving the error

`Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.TextView.ListSeparator'.`

[See this link for reason of the problem and the solution](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com.es/2011/08/new-to-android-more-style-restrictions.html). Since this post doesn't provide a code for understanding i am providing my code here

```
 <style name="Widget.TextView.ListSeparator" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>

<style name="PreferenceListHeader" parent="Widget.TextView.ListSeparator">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#cccccc</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dp</item>
</style>

<style name="PreferenceScreen" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/PreferenceListHeader</item>
    <item name="android:background">#F2B1DBF3</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I just ran into this exact problem with API level 19!

Comment: i don't see any separator line?

Comment: I have the same problem. I no longer see a divider line for the preference category. How do I enable this?

Comment: In theory, you should be able to specify your own layout and put whatever you want into it (a line or anything else). In practice, it doesn't seem to work, it's ignored.

Comment: please note Lollipop uses different styles for preferences and categories. Take a look at https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-mr1-release/core/res/res/values/styles_material.xml#L57

Comment: This will no longer compile because Widget.TextView.ListSeparator is now private. This answer helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38279736/1870884

Answer (score 15):

Styling it as described in inazaruk's answer is simple enough but it only changes the style of the text in the heading, it doesn't offer a way to specify a whole new layout (the style will not apply the `layout` item). There is, however, a straightforward solution if you extend the class:

```
public class MyPreferenceCategory extends PreferenceCategory {

  public MyPreferenceCategory(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setLayoutResource(R.layout.yourlayout);
  }

  public MyPreferenceCategory(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setLayoutResource(R.layout.yourlayout);
  }
}
```

and simply use this instead of the original `PreferenceCategory` when defining your Preferences layout.

Your layout can, of course, have anything you like, including lines above or below the text, different backgrounds, padding, whatever. For instance, this will show a material design colored subtitle with a line above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:background="?attr/divider_color" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: For me only that answer worked (Target API 21 with AppCompat)

Answer (score 11):

Like Gábor's answer but instead of extending PreferenceCategory you can do like this :
1. Make your custom layout.I named it **preference_category.xml**  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:background="?attr/divider_color" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+android:id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Important : the layout must contain a textview with this id : android:id="@+android:id/title"**

2.and in the preference add this line    :        android:layout="@layout/preference_category"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="Font_Settings"
    android:title="@string/UISetting"
    android:layout="@layout/preference_category" >
... //  other preferences in the category
</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```