# PreferenceScreen rounded corners

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences, rounded-corners

I was able to get a ListView to have rounded corners by applying this drawable as the background of the ListView,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>     

</shape>
```

I recently found out about the PreferenceScreen view, which makes my life a lot easier. However, I applied the drawable to the preference screen through a theme,

```
<style name="PreferencesTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/settingslistshape</item>
</style>
```

I've added the theme correctly to the manifest, but it doesn't do anything. I've also tried using android:background, but this rounds the corners of each row element. So how do I round the corners of the preference screen?

**EDIT:** A second after posting this question, I tried removing the top PreferenceCategory. Turns out this was covering up the rounded edges. While I'm not sure if my layout will look good with a rounded top PreferenceCategory, is there any way to do this?

I've also realized that rounding the top PreferenceCategory will only round the top of the PreferenceScreen. The bottom of the screen will still have sharp corners until I scroll to the very bottom of the view.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can customize the the PreferenceCategory like this: [Custom PreferenceCategory Headings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297635/custom-preferencecategory-headings)

I'll post back if I'm successful.

EDIT: This is how I ended up doing it, I'm really glad I learned how to make custom widgets. I used this tutorial to make a custom PreferenceCategory: http://udinic.wordpress.com/2011/08/18/dress-up-your-preferenceactivity/

You can see the code here: https://github.com/Udinic/SmallExamples/tree/master/CustomPreferenceActivity

So instead of changing the color like he did, this is my onCreateView method,

```
@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
    View newView = super.onCreateView(parent);

    newView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.preferencecategoryshape);

    return newView;

}
```

and this is my xml drawable,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dip" android:topRightRadius="10dip"/>     

</shape>
```

Hope that helps someone!