# Own design preferences screen

Tags: android, android-theme, preferencescreen

I'm trying make Preference Screen like on below image, was used style for SettingActivity in manifest and layouts for PreferenceCategory title, but i not understand, how can do widgets on screen was white color. And i don't know how can  i place title image on the top of screen (where is a text "setting").
  Anybody can help me in this question?

[image]

Comment: I guess that's a custom `Activity`, no `PreferenceScreen`

Comment: @zapl no, this is PreferenceScreen, you can see what i  had made -  [screen](http://minus.com/mbkM4QX74h/1f).

Comment: yep u right, it is. You'll need to do it similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297635/custom-preferencecategory-headings but Idk which theme/attributes apply to the items you want to have white.

Comment: @zapl oh, this could be solution, but how write there - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8066875/1173809 and there - [Android Developers](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/550fce9670530d9b/9b2b2aa389dce367?show_docid=9b2b2aa389dce367) new versions SDK Tools do not allow inherit private styles.

Comment: You can create a syle on your own, you don't need to extend an existing one

Comment: @zapl Indeed. I will try to do that, thanks for good advice.

Answer (score 0):

xml you can remove the label tag

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

//from string.xml

```
 <string name="app_name">Settings</string>
```

and add in your activity as

```
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.page_layout);
 requestwindowfeature(Window.CUSTOMTITLEBAR, R.layout.titlelayout);
```

custom title [link:](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/)