# Remove header from listView

Tags: android, listview, header

I'm having some problems when trying to remove the header from a `listView`. At first I use `addHeaderView()` to add it, but when I change to another layout I want it to disappear but `removeHeaderView()` doesn't work...

I also tried setting visibility to GONE and it doesn't disappear...

What can I do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 52):

Try the approach mentioned below..

Android `ListView#addHeaderView` and `ListView#addFooterView` methods are strange: you have to add the header and footer Views before you set the ListView's adapter so the ListView can take the headers and footers into consideration -- you get an exception otherwise. Here we add a ProgressBar (spinner) as the headerView:

// spinner is a ProgressBar

```
listView.addHeaderView(spinner);
```

We'd like to be able to show and hide that spinner at will, but removing it outright is dangerous because we'd never be able to add it again without destroying the ListView -- remember, we can't addHeaderView after we've it's adapter:

```
listView.removeHeaderView(spinner); //dangerous!
```

So let's hide it! Turns out that's hard, too. Just hiding the spinner view itself results in an empty, but still visible, header area.

[image]

Now try to hide the spinner:

```
spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Result: header area still visible with an ugly space:

[image]

The solution is to put the progress bar in a LinearLayout that wraps it's content, and hiding the content. That way the wrapping LinearLayout will collapse when its content is hidden, resulting in a headerView that is technically still present, but 0dip high:

```
<LinearLayout 
      xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- simplified -->
      <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 
  </LinearLayout>
```

Then, set the layout as the header:

```
spinnerLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_view_spinner, null);
listView.addHeaderView(spinnerLayout);
```

And when we need to hide it, hide the layout's content, not the layout:

```
spinnerLayout.findViewById(R.id.spinner).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Now the header disappears from view. No more ugly space at the top!

Comment: Great Work, Great way to explain whole process.

Comment: Things have changed. As per documentation: `When first introduced, this method could only be called before setting the adapter with setAdapter(ListAdapter). Starting with KITKAT, this method may be called at any time.`

Answer (score 17):

Most people don't like to use `AddHeaderView`, however I sometimes found it very convenient, to avoid modifying complex adapters, or if the headers are not very related to them.

With this easy trick you will be able to **seamlessly remove/add headers**:

I add an empty  `LinearLayout` with `orientation vertical`, and height `wrap_content`,  as the only Header View (let `mListView` be the target `listView`):

```
 LinearLayout mCustomHeaders=new LinearLayout(context);
 mCustomHeaders.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

 mListView.addHeaderView(mCustomHeaders);
 mListView.setAdapter (.......)
```

Thenafter, I can add random stuff, anywhere, to the list as header, even when the list is full:

```
 mCustomHeaders.add(myHeaderView1);
 mCustomHeaders.add(myHeaderView2);
 mCustomHeaders.add(myHeaderView3);
```

You can also delete all headers, anytime:

```
 mCustomHeaders.removeAllViews(); // will erase all headers
```

You get the idea .... Hope it helps !

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are always creating a new object when you do:

```
 View headerView = someView
```

So the new view is not the same as the view already added as listView header, try this:

```
View headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_datatable_saleitem_header, null, false);
        headerView.setTag(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "header");
        if (listView.getHeaderViewsCount() > 0) {
            View oldView = listView.findViewWithTag(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "header");
            if (oldView != null) {
                listView.removeHeaderView(oldView);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check if header count > 0 then remove the header and add it again.
its works fine for me.

```
 View _headerView;
 private void function HandleHeaderView(){
        if(listView.getHeaderViewsCount() > 0)
        {
            listView.removeHeaderView(_headerView);
        }

        /* Add list view header */
        _headerView = GetHeaderView();
        listView.addHeaderView(_headerView);
 }


 private View GetHeaderView()
 {
      View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_layout, null);
      // TODO: ...

      return header
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Where `drawerLogoView` is my headerview, here's what I do:

```
    drawerLogoView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer_custom_layout, null);
    mDrawerList.addHeaderView(drawerLogoView,null,false);                
    LinearLayout layOut = ((LinearLayout)drawerLogoView.findViewById(R.id.NavProfilePreviewLayout));
    layOut.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0));
```

That way, it becomes invisible :D
To show it back, you can use this:

```
    LinearLayout layOut = ((LinearLayout)drawerLogoView.findViewById(R.id.NavProfilePreviewLayout));
    layOut.setLayoutParams(newRelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using addHeaderView(), you can't delete your header after that.

So, don't use addHeaderView(). Rather, create your own adapter that
blends your main roster of Views with your header. While my
MergeAdapter will not handle your specific case, you can use it to see
the concept of blending multiple row sources:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

Comment: you can delete header view if you have a variable to point to header, see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39286390/1817569

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem in a slightly disguised scenario: the ListView I was dealing with came from PreferenceFragment, and the header represents a PreferenceCategory. So, my freedom of setting up the ListView was severely limited. But there were two approaches (partly inspired by other answers on this page). One was to add a custom layout to my PreferenceCategory (using a class that `extends android.preference.PreferenceCategory`, see *[Custom PreferenceCategory Headings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297635/custom-preferencecategory-headings)*). But I found an easier workaround: for the first Preference in this PreferenceCategory, I override `onCreateView()`:

```
@Override public View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
    parent.setTop(-parent.getChildAt(0).getTop());
    return super.onCreateView(parent);
}
```