# I want to edit Preference.xml style

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-styles

I used `Preference.xml` for setting page.

The file has PreferenceScreen, PreferenceCategory, SwitchPreference and so on. But There is a problem in Preference. When put two SwitchPreferences in PreferenceCategory, the division line which is between SwitchPreferences appears. So I want to change color of the line or remove that.

[image]

Many people use `style.xml` and change value about Preference. But I don't know how to apply style to Preference. Should I use Manifest? Then how?

please tell me detail about that.

------------------UPDATE---------------------

Here is xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Locker Mode">

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="toggle_select_mode"
        android:switchTextOff="OFF"
        android:switchTextOn="ON"
        android:summary="Change to free mode when key activated"
        />

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Notifications">

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="toggle_soundkey"
        android:switchTextOff="OFF"
        android:switchTextOn="ON"
        android:summary="Play sound when key activated"
        />

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="toggle_vibratekey"
        android:switchTextOff="OFF"
        android:switchTextOn="ON"
        android:summary="Vibrate when key activated"/>

</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Bluetooth">

    <ListPreference
        android:title="Bluetooth sensitivity"
        android:key="lp_ble_sensitivity"
        android:entries="@array/ble_sensitivity"
        android:entryValues="@array/ble_sensitivity"
        android:dialogTitle="Bluetooth sensitivity"
        />

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="User Interface">

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="toggle_appstartscan"
        android:switchTextOff="OFF"
        android:switchTextOn="ON"
        android:summary="Start scanning when App started"
        android:autoText="true"
    />

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="toggle_appfinish"
        android:switchTextOff="OFF"
        android:switchTextOn="ON"
        android:summary="Finish App when key activated"/>

</PreferenceCategory>
```

Comment: could you post your Xml file.. So that We can suggest..

Comment: @MLN I attached my xml code.

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297635/custom-preferencecategory-headings) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956823/android-preference-category-styling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code under the `preferencefragment`

```
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
// remove dividers
View rootView = getView();
ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
list.setDivider(null);

}
```

You can remove the divider using style

```
<style name="PreferenceFragment.Material">
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
</style>
```

Set the style in your PreferencesActivity

set style using `style="@style/PreferenceFragment.Material"`

Or you can do

```
   List view.setDivider(null); //as shown above
```

Comment: I know. I just want to know how to edit style in Preference

Comment: Please share your PreferenceScreen xml

Comment: my answer edited and you can set style using java also

Comment: It doesn't work. But I solve the problem with https://stackoverflow.com/a/27952333/9422444

Comment: Yes that is java code to set the styles and to remove divider I edited my answer as well. some one who is looking for the same should not confuse

Comment: Great and Your question will be helpful to many other candidates