# How to customize the style of PreferenceCategory in android?

Tags: android

I hope to change both the border of PreferenceCategory and the font of title of PreferenceCategory,how can I do? thanks!

BTW, I find some source code. but I don't know where is the definition of format="reference"

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:robobunny="http://robobunny.com"
    android:key="AppPreference"
    android:summary="@string/PreferenceSummary"
    android:title="@string/Preference" >

     <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/PreferenceCallCategory">         
        <ListPreference
          android:key="CallOption"
          android:defaultValue="OnlyAddress"       
          android:entries="@array/CallAndSMSOption"
          android:entryValues="@array/CallAndSMSOption_values"       
          android:title="@string/CallOptionTitle"
          android:summary="@string/CallOptionSummary"        
          android:layout="@layout/caller_custom_preference_layout"  
        />         
   </PreferenceCategory>             
</PreferenceScreen>




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2006 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<!-- Layout used for PreferenceCategory in a PreferenceActivity. -->
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:id="@+android:id/title"
/>


<attr name="listSeparatorTextViewStyle" format="reference" />
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Custom PreferenceCategory Headings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297635/custom-preferencecategory-headings?rq=1)?