# Change text color and horizontal color for preference category in android

Tags: android, android-preferences

I would like to change the color of my Preference category and also change the default horizontal line to blue. Is this possible?

I tried setting the theme for the preference settings with the following:

```
<style name="myPreferenceTheme"   parent="@style/AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

But I got the following as the output:

[image]

My preference.xml looks like this:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="ACCOUNT" >
    <Preference
        android:key="googleAccount"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="Google Account" >
    </Preference>
    <Preference
        android:key="signoutmenu"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="Sign out" >
    </Preference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Can somebody help me fix this issue like show in the screenshot above?

Thanks!

Comment: Its not an answer. But this may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297635/custom-preferencecategory-headings

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom PreferenceCategory and change the title color on "onBindView" method (in the example the category title color is changed to red).

```
public class MyPreferenceCategory extends PreferenceCategory {

    public MyPreferenceCategory(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyPreferenceCategory(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyPreferenceCategory(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);
        TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        titleView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
```

}

[This link has the original solution from where I got this answer](http://w3facility.org/question/how-to-change-text-color-of-preference-category-in-android/)