# Set Title style for PreferenceCategory in PreferenceFragmentCompat

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-preferences, android-styles

I want to set title style for my preference fragment screen V14.
This is what I want:
[image]

I have followed
 
[Custom PreferenceCategory Headings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297635/custom-preferencecategory-headings?rq=1)

I did manage to get the same screen but with PreferenceFragment!!
How can I do it for PreferenceFragmentCompat V14??

Here is my Code

**Style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/PreferenceStyle</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
</style>

<style name="PreferenceStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorDialogPop</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_medium</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/padding_large</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/margin_medium</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**preference.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/heading_general"
    android:layout="@layout/settings_text">

    <SwitchPreference
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:title="@string/enable_push" />

    <SwitchPreference
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:title="@string/send_email" />

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/heading_account"
    android:layout="@layout/settings_text">

    <EditTextPreference
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:title="@string/email" />

    <EditTextPreference
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:title="@string/name" />

</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**setting_text.xml** for layout of title text

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@android:id/title"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="@style/PreferenceStyle"
>

</TextView>
```

All I get is this:
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the file name be `preference_category.xml` and not `setting_text.xml`?

Comment: That is the name of layout file that I have created form custom title.

Comment: You created a custom layout `setting_text.xml` but where do you set it as default layout? The example you referred to made a copy of system layout `preference_category.xml` file in the application with the same name that's why didn't set it again. The answer below is a better approach where you created your custom layout and set it using style.

Comment: I set it in preference.xml file <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/heading_account"
    android:layout="@layout/settings_text">

Comment: below code is either incomplete or missing some code!
it is giving me same error result

Comment: I agree with Abhinav, setting the layout in the xml file is the way to go! android:layout="@layout/pref_cat_line" and in pref_cat_line, <TextView
        android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I added the Linear Layout around the Text View and the background gets visible in my choice of color.

Here is the code.

**settings_text.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/title"
    style="@style/CustomPreferenceCategoryText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="PreferenceStyle" parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
    <item name="preferenceCategoryStyle">@style/CustomPreferenceCategory</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomPreferenceCategory" parent="@style/Preference.Category">
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/settings_text</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomPreferenceCategoryText" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorDialogPop</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_medium</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/padding_large</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**preference.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/heading_general">

    <SwitchPreference
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:title="@string/enable_push" />

    <SwitchPreference
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:title="@string/send_weekly_email" />

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/heading_account">

    <EditTextPreference
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:title="@string/email" />

    <EditTextPreference
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:title="@string/name" />

</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution that I gave you but with a different layout  :/

Comment: no, the issue was the typo that I fixed in my answer

Answer (score 19):

Material style `PreferenceCategory` does not use `android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle`. Instead of trying to mess with the system styles, you can substitute a different layout for all your `PreferenceCategory`s and style that however you want.

In `res/layout/custom_preference_category.xml`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/title"
    style="@style/CustomPreferenceCategoryText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_medium" />
```

In `res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="PreferenceStyle" parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
    <item name="preferenceCategoryStyle">@style/CustomPreferenceCategory</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomPreferenceCategory" parent="@style/Preference.Category">
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/custom_preference_category</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomPreferenceCategoryText" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <!-- Style your PreferenceCategory here. -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorDialogPop</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_medium</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/padding_large</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: What is @style/PreferenceCategory?
It is not defined above!

Comment: Not working !!
I have put what you suggested with <style name="PreferenceStyle" parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
    <item name="preferenceCategoryStyle">@style/Preference.Category</item>
</style>

Comment: can you edit your code and put the correction?
<item name="preferenceCategoryStyle">@style/PreferenceCategory</item> is giving me error!!

Comment: Works fine now!

Answer (score 7):

A far simpler solution is to use `android:layout`.
Just use `@android:id/title` on the `TextView` to set the title and add any styles you may want to use.
This avoids having to deal with themes and styles.

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/your_general_title"
    android:layout="@layout/your_layout_for_categories"
    >
    :
</PreferenceCategory
```

File `your_layout_for_categories.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <!-- Just to put a simple line above -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/itemInactive"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@android:id/title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/your_own_color"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />
        <!-- or instead of using textColor use your own style -->
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is much simpler. Of course, you should specify `android:layout` to all categories - this gives you more control on what exactly you want, plus allows you to define different layouts (if you use styles as depicted above, you will end up defining several styles/themes for each category).
If your category should display an icon, use ID `@android:id/icon`. For summary, use `@android:id/summary`.

Finally, if you want to set a preference with a custom widget, use `android:widgetLayout`.
If you want to render a preference in a different way, note that the widget (say, SwitchPreference) will set only and only if you have defined a container with ID `@android:id/widget_frame`. In this way, you can actually layout all the preference UI components anywhere you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it in Kotlin:

```kotlin
class TemporyPreference @JvmOverloads constructor(
  context: Context,
  attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null,
  defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.preferenceStyle,
  defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : Preference(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PreferenceViewHolder?) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder)
    holder?.let {
      val textViewTitle = it.findViewById(android.R.id.title) as TextView
      val textViewSummary = it.findViewById(android.R.id.summary) as TextView
      textViewTitle.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.poppins_medium)
      textViewSummary.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.poppins_medium)
    }
  }
}
```

```kotlin
class TemporyPreferenceCategory @JvmOverloads constructor(
  context: Context,
  attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null,
  defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.preferenceCategoryStyle,
  defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : PreferenceCategory(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PreferenceViewHolder?) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder)
    holder?.let {
      val textViewTitle = it.findViewById(android.R.id.title) as TextView
      textViewTitle.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.poppins_semibold)
    }
  }
}
```

```xml
<PreferenceScreen>
    <com.planner.planner.ui.settings.preference.TemporyPreferenceCategory
        app:key="other_category"
        app:title="Other">

        <com.planner.planner.ui.settings.preference.TemporyPreference
            app:fragment="com.andreramon.planner.view.settings.imprint.ImprintContentFragment"
            app:key="imprint"
            app:title="@string/settings_category_about_imprint" />

        <com.planner.planner.ui.settings.preference.TemporyPreference
            app:key="@string/settings_feedback"
            app:summary="@string/settings_feedback_summary"
            app:title="@string/settings_feedback" />

    </com.planner.planner.ui.settings.preference.TemporyPreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```